# libext2fs gcc linking error

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, c, ext2

I am writing a C program which uses libext2fs:

```
#include <ext2fs/ext2fs.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    char *fsname = argv[1];
    errcode_t err;
    ext2_filsys fs;

    err= ext2fs_open(fsname, 0, 0, 0, unix_io_manager, &fs);
```

When I compile the program I get following errors:

```
$ gcc -lext2fs fstest.c -o fstest
/tmp/ccXCSICx.o: In function `main':
openfs.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `unix_io_manager'
openfs.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `ext2fs_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

System:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
- e2fsprogs, e2fslibs, e2fslibs-dev: 1.42.5-1ubuntu2

Comment: Smells like you are missing some libraries on the link line. And the provided program won't even compile, BTW.

Comment: `enedil@archlinux ~ % cat fstest.c 
#include <ext2fs/ext2fs.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    char *fsname = argv[1];
    errcode_t err;
    ext2_filsys fs;

    err= ext2fs_open(fsname, 0, 0, 0, unix_io_manager, &fs);
return 0;
}
enedil@archlinux ~ % gcc -lext2fs fstest.c -o fstest
enedil@archlinux ~ % ./fstest 
[1]    1545 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./fstest` You're missing some libraries. Do you have `build-essential` installed?

Comment: I have to wait for 8 hours before I can answer my own question, because of newbie restrictions. Will do when the waiting period is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution in the [e2fsprogs sourceforge forums](https://sourceforge.net/p/e2fsprogs/discussion/7053/thread/0b7ce9af/).
I had to put `-lext2fs` to the end of the line:

```
gcc fstest.c -o fstest -lext2fs
```

With this command it compiles now.